# Установка текста в ComboBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте. Есть ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Agents}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="ИНН:" Foreground="Red"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding INN}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="КПП:" Foreground="Red"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding KPP}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Название:" Foreground="Red"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContragentsName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Адрес:" Foreground="Red"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

При выборе из раскрывающего списка нужно, чтобы в ComboBox.Text было название организации(ContragentsName). Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `SelectedItem="{ContragentsName}"`?

Comment: Почти да. Но показывает название класса модели. (Programm.UI.Contragents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть, по крайней мере, пара способов:

1. Переопределите метод `ToString()` класса, и возвращайте в нем, то что хотите видеть в `ComboBox.Text`
2. `Text="{Binding Path=ContragentsName, Mode=OneWay}"`. С `TwoWay` тоже должно работать, причем в обе стороны, как и положено

Comment: 1 способ решил ситуацию.
2 способ показывает название класса модели.

Спасибо Вам за помощь!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Странно, что у Вас второй способ не сработал

Comment: Действительно, второй способ не работает. Это я забыл определение `ToString` убрать